# How do you make a div stay centered when using the static navigation

Tags: html, css

When ever i restore the window or test screen resolution on screenfly.

the content where my html5 player is at hides into the navigation.

here is the website
http://djwckd.com/

css

```
    #sidenav {
        background-image:url('http://i1285.photobucket.com/albums/a592/djwckd/wckd-bg2_zps36505f8f.jpg');
        width: 225px;
        position: fixed; /*--Fix the sidenav to stay in one spot--*/
        float: left; /*--Keeps sidenav into place when Fixed positioning fails--*/
        text-align:center;
        height: 100%;   
    }

#content {
    background-image:url('http://i1285.photobucket.com/albums/a592/djwckd/wckd-bg1_zpsf32da4c1.jpg');
    float: right; /*--Keeps content to the right side--*/
    width:85%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS;
    color: #000;
    height: 100%;

}

.bottom {
    background-image:url('http://i1285.photobucket.com/albums/a592/djwckd/wckd-bg3_zps849e973b.png');
    font-family:Trebuchet MS;
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    font-size:12px;
    color: #777777;
}

.copy {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS;
    font-size:14px;
    height: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `min-width` to the container of both the sidebar and content fixes the issue, but would add scrollbars on browsers with width less than the minimum width specified.

```
div.container { min-width:1024px; }
```

This prevents the container ever going smaller than 1024px.

Comment: is there a way for the whole website to shrink and  stay the same size at any resolution?

Comment: Using Media Queries, you can adjust the sizes of elements specific to certain resolutions: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ & http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/